# How to merge rows in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I want to merge the rows in Slickgrid, does anyone have any idea?
Something like this where i want to merge header rows with 0

[image: Something like this where i want to merge header rows with 0]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the 6pac/SlickGrid fork, you should browse through the list of [Examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples), there's [ColSpan](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-colspan.html) and [Column Header Grouping](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-column-group.html)

Comment: ColSpan is used to merge Columns, but in my case i want to merge Rows

Comment: @ashaganapathy your question is not very clear, perhaps draw a rectangle on what you're trying to achieve. Because from your print screen I can clearly see that the Column Header Grouping is in use but still you say that it's not what you're looking for... please be more specific in your question

Comment: I have a feeling that what you're looking for is this [RowSpan](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/SlickGrid/blob/k0stya-rowspan/examples/example-0032-row-span-many-columns.html) which is only available in the `GerHobbelt/SlickGrid` fork and is not currently in the `6pac/SlickGrid` fork. These are all Open Source project, you are most welcome to contribute and add more functionalities.